# about Java's classpath setting on Linux

Tags: java

everyone.

I used openjdk-7 on arch linux. I started to learn Java recently, and encountered such a problem:

I created a file at /home/hqwrong/Code/java/mew/Mouth.java:

```
package mew;

public class Mouth{
   public static void main(String argv[]){
       pickle.Say s = new pickle.Say();
  }
}
```

and another one at /home/hqwrong/Code/java/pickle/Say.java :

```
package pickle;

public class Say{
   public Say(){
      System.out.println("Say");
   }
}
```

I compiled Say.java to Say.class,using:

```
$ cd /home/hqwrong/Code/java/pickle
$ javac Say.java
```

which is successful.

I compiled Mouth.java ,using:

```
$ cd ../mew
$ export CLASSPATH=.:/home/hqwrong/Code/java/
$ javac Say.java
```

no error message.

But after I type:

$ java Say

I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.mew
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:649)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:785)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:472)
```

It's same when I use:

```
$ java -cp $CLASSPATH Say
```

I need your help,please?

Comment: Are you showing the code as is or you modified it for this question? I suspect that in your code you might have `package java.mew'?

Comment: @anubhava its initial value is nothing, I don't know why it compiles and works successfully until I did this package-testing, Maybe it knows the jdk system lib path through some other way.

Comment: @laixer yes,it is the original one.I'm learning java, this is my code to learn java's package functionality. It also fails, after modified to package java.mew.

Comment: Sorry, that's good. You should not have "package java.something" in your code. "package mew" or "package pickle" is okay to have. I was just checking if there was a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is no good answer yet, I'll post mine.

First, you should really have a separate folder for your classes and your sources. I suggest using `java/src` for your sources, and `java/classes` for your classes. Since the classes are stored in the classes folder, this is the one that should be in the classpath.

The folder tree of your sources should then match your package tree. This means that the class mew.Mouth must contain the line `package mew`, be defined in the Mouth.java file, in the `java/src/mew` folder.

To compile your classes, put you in the `java/src` directory, and use the following command:

```
javac -d ../classes mew/Mouth.java pickle/Say.java
```

The compiler will automatically generate the folder structure matching the package structure in the classes directory. If you make structural modifications in your source tree, just remove everything in the classes folder, and recompile everything.

To run your classes, you must refer to their fully qualified name. And the folder containing your package tree (the `java/classes` folder) must be in the classpath. Once this is done, from everywhere, you can use

```
java mew.Mouth
```

Note that, as you have discovered, the `java` and `javax` packages are reserved. You can't use them for your own classes.

Comment: This answer just helped me as well. Thank you very much! ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

open your root folder, Go to view Menu & tick , view hidden files. Now It will display a file called ".bashrc". open this file & write down following lines of code,

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.6.0_21/bin
export PATH
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_21
export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think the answer is I typed a wrong class name as MockerTim said.

Comment: thats ok, this is for classpath settings as your question title describes.

Comment: can you please atleast voteup my answer so that it can be useful for others